# VHDL 2 process state machine and output initialization

Tags: vhdl, state-machine

So Altera provides an example of a 2 process state machine a [this link](http://quartushelp.altera.com/15.0/mergedProjects/hdl/vhdl/vhdl_pro_state_machines.htm).

I kinda like this style, but what I don't understand is that if 'input' stays at '0', the second process is never triggered as the state never changes, and 'output' is therefore never assigned nor initialized... Or is it ?

My understanding is that there need to be a transition on one of the sensitivity list signal ('state' in this example) which could never occur here.

Could someone please clarify what's the deal here ?

Here's the code :

```
ENTITY state_machine IS
   PORT(
      clk      : IN   STD_LOGIC;
      input    : IN   STD_LOGIC;
      reset    : IN   STD_LOGIC;
      output   : OUT  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(1 downto 0));
END state_machine;
ARCHITECTURE a OF state_machine IS
   TYPE STATE_TYPE IS (s0, s1, s2);
   SIGNAL state   : STATE_TYPE;
BEGIN
   PROCESS (clk, reset)
   BEGIN
      IF reset = '1' THEN
         state <= s0;
      ELSIF (clk'EVENT AND clk = '1') THEN
         CASE state IS
            WHEN s0=>
               IF input = '1' THEN
                  state <= s1;
               ELSE
                  state <= s0;
               END IF;
            WHEN s1=>
               IF input = '1' THEN
                  state <= s2;
               ELSE
                  state <= s1;
               END IF;
            WHEN s2=>
               IF input = '1' THEN
                  state <= s0;
               ELSE
                  state <= s2;
               END IF;
         END CASE;
      END IF;
   END PROCESS;

   PROCESS (state)
   BEGIN
      CASE state IS
         WHEN s0 =>
            output <= "00";
         WHEN s1 =>
            output <= "01";
         WHEN s2 =>
            output <= "10";
      END CASE;
   END PROCESS;

END a;
```

**EDIT:**
Just to clarify, my question is: it looks to me that 'output' will be in a undefined state until 'input' transitions to '1'. Isn't that bad practice, considering this is an official example from Altera ?
And by the way, what would be the proper way of initializing 'output' here ? With async reset ?

Comment: Each process will execute until suspended during initialization (IEEE Std 1076-2008 14.7.5.2 Initialization). The initial value of `state` will be s0 regardless of reset (14.4 Elaboration of a declarative part, 14.4.2.5 Object declarations, 6.4.2.3 Signal declarations). During initialization the assignment to `output` will schedule a value update to "00" at time 0. In the first simulation cycle the change in effective value from "UU" to "00" will cause an event on `output`. (14.7.3.2 Driving values, 14.7.3.3 Effective values, 14.7.3.4 Signal update, 14.7.5.3 Simulation cycle).

Comment: user1155120 is right. Altough to be code-complete (i.e. make the code more readible) I would write `SIGNAL state   : STATE_TYPE := s0;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ...it looks to me that 'output' will be in a undefined state until
>   'input' transitions to '1'.

No (see below). At the beginning of the simulation, `output` will immediately take value `"00"`, even if the reset is not asserted and there is no transition on `input`.

> Isn't that bad practice, considering this is an official example from
>   Altera ?

No, this code is fine. The state register (`state`) can be properly initialized, thanks to the reset, and `output` combinatorialy depends on `state`. This model will behave as expected, both in simulation and in hardware.

> And by the way, what would be the proper way of initializing 'output'
>   here ? With async reset ?

You don't initialize outputs of combinatorials with reset. Resets (asynchronous or synchronous) are used to initialize registers (`state`, in your example).

Sensitivity lists are just syntactical sugar. A process with sensitivity list is equivalent to the same process, without sensitivity list, and with a `wait on <sensitivity-list>;` as the **last** statement. Example:

```
PROCESS (state)
BEGIN
  CASE state IS
     WHEN s0 =>
        output <= "00";
     WHEN s1 =>
        output <= "01";
     WHEN s2 =>
        output <= "10";
  END CASE;
END PROCESS;
```

is equivalent to:

```
PROCESS
BEGIN
  CASE state IS
     WHEN s0 =>
        output <= "00";
     WHEN s1 =>
        output <= "01";
     WHEN s2 =>
        output <= "10";
  END CASE;
  WAIT ON state;
END PROCESS;
```

So, this process is triggered (as all processes) at the beginning of the simulation, and it assigns a value to `output`. In your particular case, this value will be `"00"` because the initial value of `state` is the leftmost value of its enumerated type, that is, `s0`. All in all, `output` is initialized to `"UU"` (`U` is the leftmost value of enumerated type `std_logic`) and, after the very first simulation step (at T=0), it takes value `"00"`.

Note: this code is fine and a good representative of coding for a Moore state machine (not Mealy, as other answers state: the outputs depend only on the current state). But it has (at least) two small problems:

1. It uses the `std_logic` resolved type for single-drive signals, which is not a very good idea. `std_ulogic` and `std_ulogic_vector` would be much better and much safer.
2. It uses the names `input` and `output` which, while not reserved words of the language, should be avoided: they are the standard input and output streams defined in `std.textio`.

Comment: `output` wont take value `00` immediately if reset is never toggled.

Comment: I am sorry, Javia1492, but you are wrong. You should take a better look at the VHDL semantics. Or try by yourself, it takes 2 minutes to simulate this design.

Comment: Ok thanks Renaud. I didn't know the state process would be triggered once even with no transition on state itself. I'm perfectly happy with that answer. And I thought I saw 'UU' in my simulator, but just re-did it and it outputs '00' from the start. Thx ;)

Comment: It's not "triggered' it's initialized and there is an order dependency that requires `state` has been initialized before the process assigning `output` is executed during initialization. Every process is executed during initialization until it suspends. Any transactions in driver projected output waveforms at the current or a future simulation time that will cause events stimulate the design model to continue simulation. Your "UU" would be updated to "00" in the first simulation cycle, occurring without advancing simulation time, the waveform element after time_expression defaults to 0.

Comment: Seeing your answer about using `std_ulogic`: although it might be better/wiser, I've encountered issues when integrating with EDA tools and especially when connecting to third party IP. Everybody is using `std_logic` and has been doing so for decades, so it's not really easy to switch. I would not advice to do so.

Comment: @JHBonarius I see your point. I usually solve this with a top-level wrapper that just converts `std_ulogic` to `std_logic`. It's one more level in the hierarchy but it's simple and limits the risks. Moreover, this wrapper can also do other useful things like 1) instantiating the vendor-dependent macros (IOBUF...) and thus keep the lower levels more vendor-agnostic, 2) convert structured types (axi_master2slave record) to individual ports, 3) allow to synthesize the lower levels with a third party tool and the top level with your vendor's tool...